# Why is the force on each of my robot's four legs different?

Tags: webots

Why is the force on each of my robot's four legs different? (The robot has a mass of 500g, each leg has no mass, and the pad at the end of the leg is 10g.) I believe that theoretically, the force on each of the four legs should be -0.125 * 9.8N, which can accept errors. However, in reality, the left front and right hind are strong, and the right front and left hind are not. The force and robot are arranged as shown in the figure, The force of the four legs is calculated by Jacobi and the joint torque of the motor (Jacobi confirms that it is correct)

I have checked Jacobi and confirmed that there is no mistake. I tried to adjust the initial posture of the robot, shifting the left forward and right hind downwards by 0.0003. The force on the four legs will become slightly uniform, but when I modeled, the four legs were on the same plane, so I think this solution is unhealthy